# How can I install PaperPort 8 (and PaperPort color) as a printer on Windows Vista 64-bit?

Tags: windows-vista, drivers

A friend has a PaperPort 8 license that he got from his dad and he's installed it. The problem is that PaperPort isn't appearing in the printer menu. Is there some other driver that needs to be installed? He's running Windows Vista Home Premium Service Pack 2, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of the software you have does not support Windows Vista.  The version of Paper Port your friend recieved was released almost a decade before Windows Vista was even released.

[Source](http://www.nuance.com/vista/paperport/upgrade/)